# Why "npm install" overrides node modules in an existing symlink?

Tags: node.js, npm, symlink, npm-install

I'm working on javascript/Node/React modules. I develop:

- 1 module **A** with common features
- Others modules **B**, C, D ... with a dependency to A.

I need to be able to develop on **A** and **B** at the same time. That's why, after doing `npm install` in **B**, I create a symlink from **B** to **A** with `npm link ../A`. I am then able to launch a webpack dev server from **A**, a webpack dev server from **B** and therefore, any modification to **A** will impact **B**. This ways all works fine to me at this point.

My problem is that if I launch command `npm install` from **B**, it will keep the symlink to **A** and remove several node modules from **A** repository. I don't know why? I would like to keep the existing symlink **A** alive and have B ignore it when re-installing.

A first solution for me is to fill npm scripts post-install & pre-install to do a `rimraf` of symlink before installing **B** node modules and to re-generate symlink Thereafter. But it is a problem for developers that doesn't work on **A** and doesn't requires any symlinks...

I just update npm from 2 to 3 and I doesn't find any answers on how `npm install` interacts with existing symlinks.

I'm using:

- npm 3.10.3
- node 6.3.0

Thank for any idea or link that could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood what append doing additional tests. It seems the behaviors I described comes from 'shrinkwrap.json' ways. Whatever appends in the folder **A**, if I install (`npm install`) **B** with an existing `shrinkwrap.json` in **B**, the `shrinkwrap` rules are followed.

In my case, there are dev dependencies loaded in **A**. Those dev dependencies are not listed in `shrinkwrap.json` from **B**. As a result, **A** is altered when reinstalling **B**.

I can produce the inverse problem: If I install **A** and do `npm shrinkwrap` in **B**, I'll have numerous error like "`npm ERR! extraneous:`"

It seems locking dependencies without the dev dependencies can't fit with doing npm symlinks to folder installed in 'dev mode' - aka with dev dependencies installed.